# How to automatically fill a form

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a sample application that when executed it will automatically check a checkbox "of the current page" (the id is hard-coded in the script).

I tried the following code, but nothing is happened (the check box is still unchcked.

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type = "button" onclick="check"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
function check()
{
    document.getElementById('hard_coded_id').checked = true;
}
```

what's wrong with this code. Please help me.

**EDIT**

the "hard_coded_id" is a checkbox from a web site like "www.hello.com". when this site is opened, and when my app starts I want that the checkbox will be checked.

I'll ask my question **differently**, is it possible to create an app extension that will fill automatically the google search textbox when the google site is loaded.

Comment: id is missing for input

Comment: No, becouse he doesn't want to diable button. I think that code like: <input id="hard_coded_id" type="checkbox" checked="" name="hard_coded_id"> was removed on purpose.

Comment: No the "hard_coded_id" is from an other website

Comment: Is test.html for testing that you've done things correctly,  or is actually part of your extension?  Could you post your manifest?

Comment: I'll ask my question differently, is it possible to create an app extension that will fill automatically the google search textbox when the google site is loaded.

Comment: It is possible to create an extension to automatically fill a form.  The most important part of an extension is the manifest.json file.  Without it, it's hard to tell what you expect your files to be doing.  Whether you need test.html depends on your answer to my previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to check a checkbox (or rather fill textboxes) on a certain page. All you need to do is to mention your extension script in the `content_scripts` section of your manifest and provide it with the correct matches

Example

```
"content_scripts": [ {
   "js": [ "test.js" ],
   "matches": [ "http://www.hello.com/*" ]
} ],
```

Your `test.js` will be injected into the page, so it will be run outside the scope of your extension and inside the scope of the web page. With a mechanism like `window.onload` or `$(document).ready()` if you use jQuery, you can make your script wait until the destination page has finished loading

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   check();
});

function check()
{
   document.getElementById('hard_coded_id').checked = true;
}
```

given that `hard_coded_id` exists on the destination page

Comment: should I delete the test.html file? or it's mandatory in the project?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type = "button" onclick="check()"/>
    </body>
 </html>
```

anyway this is the correct way to create checkbox (checked attribute is not necessary):

```
<input id="hard_coded_id" type="checkbox" checked="" name="hard_coded_id">
```

Comment: I don't understand how do you want to check checkbox on the other page? From test.html?

Comment: like auto fill applications. when the website is opened the app automatically fill the form of this page.